# Can correlated subquery following is not null check be replaced with joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can this correlated subquery, where the subquery follows is not null check on the foreign key, be replaced with joins? Example:

```
select * from TableABC as t
where 
(t.label_id is null or t.label_id in ( select t1.id from Labels as t1 where t1.type = '123'))
and
(t.tag_id is null or t.tag_id in ( select t2.id from Tags as t2 where t2.type = '123'))
```

Described by words: Let's say, I'm looking for all records where if they have *label* reference defined then the label must be of certain type; same apply for *tags*.

Or could this query be improved by other means?

It is intended for TSQL (MS SQL).

UPDATE:
I have added table aliases as hinted by HABO. Hope it will improve readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is an improvement, but it does use `left outer join` instead of correlated subqueries.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @TableABC as Table( ABCId Int Identity, LabelId Int, TagId Int );
declare @Labels as Table( LabelId Int Identity, Label VarChar(3) );
declare @Tags as Table( TagId Int Identity, Tag VarChar(3) );

insert into @Labels ( Label ) values ( '123' ), ( '12' ), ( '123' );
insert into @Tags ( Tag ) values ( '123' ), ( '213' ), ( '123' ), ( '312' );
insert into @TableABC ( LabelId, TagId ) values
  ( 1, 1 ), ( 1, 2 ), ( 1, 3 ), ( 1, 4 ),
  ( 2, 1 ), ( 2, 2 ), ( 2, 3 ), ( 2, 4 ),
  ( 3, 1 ), ( 3, 2 ), ( 3, 3 ), ( 3, 4 ),
  ( NULL, 1 ), ( NULL, 3 ), ( 1, NULL ), ( 3, NULL ), ( NULL, NULL );

select ABC.ABCId, ABC.LabelId, ABC.TagId,
  L.LabelId as L_LabelId, L.Label as L_Label,
  case when ABC.LabelId is NULL or L.Label = '123' then '<<<' else '' end as 'L_Match',
  T.TagId as T_TagId, T.Tag as T_Tag,
  case when ABC.TagId is NULL or T.Tag = '123' then '<<<' else '' end as 'T_Match'
  from @TableABC as ABC left outer join
    @Labels as L on L.LabelId = ABC.LabelId left outer join
    @Tags as T on T.TagId = ABC.TagId;

-- "Original" query:
select *
  from @TableABC
  where ( LabelId is null or LabelId in ( select LabelId from @Labels where Label = '123' ) ) and
    ( TagId is null or TagId in ( select TagId from @Tags where Tag = '123' ) );

-- Left outer joins:
select ABC.*
  from @TableABC as ABC left outer join
    @Labels as L on L.LabelId = ABC.LabelId and L.Label = '123' left outer join
    @Tags as T on T.TagId = ABC.TagId and T.Tag = '123'
  where ( ABC.LabelId is NULL or L.LabelId is not NULL ) and ( ABC.TagId is NULL or T.TagId is not NULL );
```

Tip: Always use helpful table aliases with joins and apply them to all columns.

Comment: So standard `left outer join` followed by `t.label_id is NULL or t1.id is not NULL) and (t.tag_id is NULL and t2.id is not NULL)` did the trick, that was exactly what I was looking for! Tested and verified on a real business case data, it works. Thank you. And by the way, you are right, it's not an improvement in any sense, even performance wise it is the same as original.

Answer (score 2):

I would be inclined to write this as:

```
select t.*
from TableABC abc
where (abc.label_id is null or
       exists (select 1 from labels where l.id = abc.label_id and l.type = 123)
      ) and
      (abc.tag_id is null or
       exists (select 1 from tags t where t.id = abc.tag_id and t.type = 123)
      );
```

Then I would be sure I have in index on `labels(id, type)` and `tags(id, type)` (if the `id`s are not already primary keys).

However, your version would probably also  have a reasonable execution plan with the right indexes.

Comment: Thank you, I tested your solution, it definitively works, and yes again, there was no performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

With a union

```
select * 
from TableABC 
where TableABC.label_id is null

union all

select * 
from TableABC 
join Labels 
  on TableABC.label_id = Lables.id 
 and Lablestype = '123'
```

`on TableABC.label_id = Lables.id or TableABC.label_id is null` would return too many rows

Comment: You are right, using `union all + right join` is another correct solution and a working alternative. Your answer is however badly formatted and incomplete; it's missing the second joined table. Please fix it and I am happy to add points.

Comment: I made figured out that for the three table with two joins scenario one has to make union of 4 queries: one were `label_id is null and tag_id is null`, `label_id is not null and tag_id is null` with joined labels, `label_id is null and tag_id is not null` with joined tags and finally `label_id is not null and tag_id is not null` with joined both labels and tags. Right? At least that was worked for me. Which makes really big query and the slowest solution.